# Delete all files from within a directory that contain a specific word

Tags: delete, find, rm

I have navigated to a specific directory on the file system and wish to delete all files within the directory that contain 'sofa_' in their file name.

Can someone please suggest how this can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all files are in the same directory (no subdirectories) just run:

```
rm *sofa_*
```

If you need this to descend into subdirectories, either use `find`:

```
find . -name "*sofa_*" -type f -delete
```

Or, if you are using `bash`, enable the `globstar` option which makes `**` match all files and 0 or more subdirectories (making it recursive):

```
shopt -s globstar
```

Then:

```
rm **/*sofa_*
```

Answer (score 4):

```
find . -name "*sofa_*" -type f | xargs rm
```

Or as correctly noted in the comments:

```
find . -name "*sofa_*" -type f -delete
```